# How can I project texture from different object with texture and alpha on to another model?

Tags: texturing

I have 2 separate model of a scalp and body. What I'm trying to achieve is that I want to paint / transfer the scalp texture onto the body so I won't have to deal with extra vertices.

The scalp object has an alpha to it. So how can I transfer the texture data from the scalp to the head?

[image]

[image]

Comment: Have you tried to bake it? (Active to Selected object) I'm not sure if it works with transparency. If not you could try to mix in the skin color to replace the transparency.

Comment: I did. Baking just messed up the whole texture overall.